# How to change value in input element? (reactjs)

Tags: reactjs

What I'm trying to do is that if user click on button 'Edit', modal is opened, and in value of input fields should be old, not updated value. But when I do that, I can't write anything else.

(eg. if user wants to update name, by opening modal EditUser, the old value of users name should be there, in input filed, and user needs to have opportunity to change that.)

```
<Input 
    type="text" 
    onChange={(e: any) => setFirstNameUpdated(e.target.value)} 
    value={props.userInfo.firstName}>        
</Input>
```

i tried to use useRef:

```
const inputNameRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | any>(null)

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(inputNameRef.current)     // this is null
    console.log(props.userInfo.firstName) // this is OK
    inputNameRef.current && (inputNameRef.current.value=props.userInfo.firstName)
}, [])

<Input 
    type="text" 
    onChange={(e: any) => setFirstNameUpdated(e.target.value)} 
    ref={inputNameRef}>        
</Input>
```

EDIT:
SinglePost.tsx

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter, Button, FormGroup, Label, Input } from 'reactstrap'
import Axios from 'axios'
import '../user_profile/myprofile.css'

function UpdateProfile(props: any) {

    const [firstNameUpdated, setFirstNameUpdated] = useState('')
    const [lastNameUpdated, setLastNameUpdated] = useState('')
    const [userBioUpdated, setUserBioUpdated] = useState('')

    const inputNameRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | any>(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(inputNameRef.current, props.userInfo.firstName)
        inputNameRef.current && (inputNameRef.current.value = props.userInfo.firstName)
    }, [])

    // upload image
    const [file, setFile] = useState('')
    const [uploaded, setUploaded] = useState('')

    const handleImageUpload = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setFile(e.target.files[0])
    };

    const onClickHandler = (e: any) => {
        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('fileImage', file)

        Axios.post("/api/image", formData, {})
            .then(res => {
                //console.log(`UPLOADED: http://localhost:5000/${res.data.fileImage}`)
                setUploaded(`http://localhost:5000/${res.data.fileImage}`)
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    // update user
    const updateUser = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        props.setIsEditOpen(false)

        const formData = new FormData()

        formData.append('fileImage', file)
        formData.append('first_name', firstNameUpdated)
        formData.append('last_name', lastNameUpdated)
        formData.append('user_bio', userBioUpdated)

        const config: any = { header: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" } }

        Axios
            .put(`/api/users/${props.userID}`, formData, config)
            .then(res => {
                const user = res.data
                props.setUserInfo({
                    firstName: user.first_name,
                    lastName: user.last_name,
                    userBio: user.user_bio,
                    userPhoto: user.profile_image
                })
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {props.isEditOpen &&
                <Modal isOpen={props.isEditOpen} toggle={() => props.setIsEditOpen(!props.isEditOpen)} backdrop="static">
                    <ModalHeader>Update your profile</ModalHeader>
                    <ModalBody>
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Label>Profile Image</Label>
                            <Input type="file" name="fileImage" onChange={handleImageUpload}></Input>
                        </FormGroup>
                        <Button onClick={onClickHandler} className="btn-upload-img">Upload file</Button>
                        <div className="inline">
                            {uploaded ? <img src={uploaded} style={{ width: "100px" }}></img> : <img  src={props.userInfo.userPhoto} style={{ width: "100px" }}></img>}
                        </div>
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Label>First Name</Label>
                            <Input type="text" onChange={(e: any) => setFirstNameUpdated(e.target.value)} ref={inputNameRef} value={firstNameUpdated}></Input>
                        </FormGroup>
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Label>Last Name</Label>
                            <Input type="text" onChange={(e: any) => setLastNameUpdated(e.target.value)} defaultValue={props.userInfo.lastName}></Input>
                        </FormGroup>
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Label>About me</Label>
                            <Input type="text" onChange={(e: any) => setUserBioUpdated(e.target.value)} defaultValue={props.userInfo.userBio}></Input>
                        </FormGroup>
                    </ModalBody>
                    <ModalFooter>
                        <Button color="success" onClick={updateUser} className="btn-update">Update</Button>
                        <Button color="danger" onClick={() => props.setIsEditOpen(false)}>Cancel</Button>
                    </ModalFooter>
                </Modal>}
        </div>
    )
}

export default UpdateProfile
```

MyProfile.tsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react'
import './myprofile.css'
import Axios from 'axios'
import SinglePost from '../single_post/SinglePost'
import { AppContext } from '../context/AppContext'
import UpdateProfile from '../modals/UpdateProfile'

function MyProfile() {

    const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        userBio: 'Write something about yourself.',
        userPhoto: ''
    })
    const [isEditOpen, setIsEditOpen] = useState(false)

    const { userID, setUserID } = useContext(AppContext)

    // open modal on click 'edit'
    const editUser = () => {
        setIsEditOpen(true)
    }

    // get user data
    const storedToken = localStorage.getItem('token')

    useEffect(() => {
        const config = {
            headers: { "x-auth-token": `${storedToken}` }
        }
        Axios
            .get('/api/auth/user', config)
            .then(res => {
                console.log('response', res)
                const user = res.data.user
                setUserID(user._id)
                setUserInfo({
                    firstName: user.first_name,
                    lastName: user.last_name,
                    userBio: user.user_bio,
                    userPhoto: user.profile_image
                })
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }, [])


    return (
        <div className="profile-container">
            <button className="btn-edit" onClick={editUser}>
                <i className="fa fa-edit"></i>
            </button>
            <div className="user-info">
                <div className="img-circular">
                    <img className="user-profile-img2" src={userInfo.userPhoto}></img>
                </div>
                <p className="user-name">{userInfo.firstName} {userInfo.lastName}</p>
                <p className="about-user">{userInfo.userBio}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="user-posts">
                <p className="my-posts-title">My Posts</p>
            </div>
            {isEditOpen && <UpdateProfile
                userID={userID}
                setIsEditOpen={setIsEditOpen}
                isEditOpen={isEditOpen}
                setUserInfo={setUserInfo}
                userInfo={userInfo}
            />}
            {/* <SinglePost /> */}
        </div>
    )
}

export default MyProfile
```

Comment: What does `setFirstNameUpdated` do? Does it update the local state or parent state? What is `props.userInfo`? Please add a bit more code. Looks like you're not updating the state properly.

Comment: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/react-controlled-forms-with-hooks-538762aab935

Comment: Instead of `value={...}` try using `defaultValue`

Comment: @Siddhard `setFirstNameUpdated` sets the firstName of user to my database.. i edited and added more code so you can see 
@jdaz i tried but if I click on btn 'update' and i don't write anything, it saves me nothing, empty string